# Pandas Resample Apply Custom Function?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to use pandas to resample 15 minute periods into 1 hour periods but by applying a custom function. My DataFrame is in this format;

```
Date                      val1       val2                  
2016-01-30 07:00:00       49.0       45.0
2016-01-30 07:15:00       49.0       44.0
2016-01-30 07:30:00       52.0       47.0
2016-01-30 07:45:00       60.0       46.0
2016-01-30 08:00:00       63.0       61.0
2016-01-30 08:15:00       61.0       60.0
2016-01-30 08:30:00       62.0       61.0
2016-01-30 08:45:00       63.0       61.0
2016-01-30 09:00:00       68.0       60.0
2016-01-30 09:15:00       71.0       70.0
2016-01-30 09:30:00       71.0       70.0
```

..and i want to resample with this function;

```
def log_add(array_like):
    return (10*math.log10((sum([10**(i/10) for i in array_like])))))
```

I do;

```
df.resample('1H').apply(log_add)
```

but this returns an empty df, doing this;

```
df.resample('1H').apply(lambda x: log_add(x))
```

does the same too. Anyone any ideas why its not applying the function properly?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I think you want to use `df.resample('1H').agg (...)` (don't quote me on it). Resample object is pretty much a groupby now.

Answer (score 4):

You can add parameter `on` what is implemented in [0.19.0 pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#other-enhancements):

```
print (df.resample('1H', on='Date').apply(log_add))
```

Or set `Date` to `index` by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
print (df.resample('1H').apply(log_add))
```

Also first check if `dtype` of column `Date` is `datetime`, if not use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
print (df.dtypes)
Date     object
val1    float64
val2    float64
dtype: object

df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)

print (df.dtypes)
Date    datetime64[ns]
val1           float64
val2           float64
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this didn't work unfortunately; Date is already the index and the resample works for normal functions like 'sum' for example so i'm thinking my custom func is at fault but not sure why?

Comment: @JasonB A couple points. Use `numpy` instead of `math` and if you are using python 2, your function won't work properly because of the integer division. rerun your code with `from __future__ import division`

Comment: Thanks for the points- duly noted. I'm currently using Python 3 too.

Comment: I test it with pandas 0.19.1 and python 3 and for me it works perfectly. Problem is with samle also?

Comment: @Ted Apologies, I've rerun this with np.log10 and it works perfectly! Thanks very much, that's great- i'd have been on this for ages otherwise.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with `.apply(func, args=(arg1,))`

Comment: What about `.apply(lambda x: func(arg1,))` ?