# looking for better iteration approach for slicing a dataframe

Tags: python, numpy, iteration, slice

First post: I apologize in advance for sloppy wording (and possibly poor searching if this question has been answered ad nauseum elsewhere - maybe I don't know the right search terms yet).

I have data in 10-minute chunks and I want to perform calculations on a column ('input') grouped by minute (i.e. 10 separate 60-second blocks - not a rolling 60 second period) and then store all ten calculations in a single list called output.

The 'seconds' column records the second from 1 to 600 in the 10-minute period. If no data was entered for a given second, there is no row for that number of seconds.  So, some minutes have 60 rows of data, some have as few as one or two.

Note: the calculation (my_function) is not basic so I can't use groupby and np.sum(), np.mean(), etc. - or at least I can't figure out how to use groupby.

I have code that gets the job done but it looks ugly to me so I am sure there is a better way (probably several).

```
output=[]

seconds_slicer = 0

for i in np.linspace(1,10,10):
    seconds_slicer += 60
    minute_slice = df[(df['seconds'] > (seconds_slicer - 60)) & 
                             (df['seconds'] <= seconds_slicer)]
    calc = my_function(minute_slice['input'])
    output.append(calc)
```

If there is a cleaner way to do this, please let me know.  Thanks!

Edit: Adding sample data and function details:

```
seconds input
1   1   0.000054
2   2   -0.000012
3   3   0.000000
4   4   0.000000
5   5   0.000045

def realized_volatility(series_log_return):
    return np.sqrt(np.sum(series_log_return**2))
```

Comment: Seeing what your function does, or some sample input and expected output would help us to understand the nature of your question. On the face of it, it looks a lot like doing a standard resample in pandas, does this link help? [Pandas Resample Apply Custom Function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41300653/pandas-resample-apply-custom-function)

Comment: I was trying to do this without converting the seconds column to datetime (but maybe that is what I should do).  I am about to add a data sample and the details of the function in the original post.  I left the function details out originally because I was focused on the slicing and didn't want to clutter with details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this answer, we're going to repurpose [Bin pandas dataframe by every X rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20180324/bin-pandas-dataframe-by-every-x-rows)

We'll create a dataframe with missing data in the 'seconds' column, as I understand your data to be based on the description given

```
secs=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,12,14,15,17,19]
data = [np.random.randint(-25,54)/100000 for _ in range(15)]

df=pd.DataFrame(data=zip(secs,data), columns=['seconds','input'])

df

    seconds input
0   1   0.00017
1   2   -0.00020
2   3   0.00033
3   4   0.00052
4   5   0.00040
5   6   -0.00015
6   7   0.00001
7   8   -0.00010
8   9   0.00037
9   11  0.00050
10  12  0.00000
11  14  -0.00009
12  15  -0.00024
13  17  0.00047
14  19  -0.00002
```

I didn't create 600 rows, but that's okay, we'll say we want to bin every 5 seconds instead of every 60. Now, because we're just trying to use equal time measures for grouping, we can just use floor division to see which bin each time interval *would* end up in. (In your case, you'd divide by 60 instead)

```
grouped=df.groupby(df['seconds'] // 5).apply(realized_volatility).drop('seconds', axis=1) #we drop the extra 'seconds' column because we don;t care about the root sum of squares of seconds in the df

grouped

        input
seconds 
0       0.000441
1       0.000372
2       0.000711
3       0.000505
```

Comment: Very nice solution.  Thanks!

Comment: Happy to help, thanks for providing the sample info so I could help