# Plot area charts with different colors for time series data based on multiple condtions in Matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

Given a small dataset as follows:

```
         date  value  type
0  2021-07-31   6.32     1
1  2021-08-31   5.93     1
2  2021-09-30   5.43     2
3  2021-10-30   4.72     2
4  2021-11-30   4.23     3
5  2021-12-31   3.96     3
```

or:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': {0: '2021-07-31',
  1: '2021-08-31',
  2: '2021-09-30',
  3: '2021-10-30',
  4: '2021-11-30',
  5: '2021-12-31'},
 'value': {0: 6.32, 1: 5.93, 2: 5.43, 3: 4.72, 4: 4.23, 5: 3.96},
 'type': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 3, 5: 3}})
```

I hope to draw area charts based on `type`, ie., for date where if `type=1, 2, 3`, I will use color `gray`, `lightpink` and `skyblue` respecitvely.

How could I do that? Thanks.

The expected plot will like this:

[image]

Reference code:

```
year_n_1 = [1.5, 3, 10, 13, 22, 36, 30, 33, 24.5, 15, 6.5, 1.2]
year_n = [2, 7, 14, 17, 20, 27, 30, 38, 25, 18, 6, 1]

plt.fill_between(np.arange(12), year_n_1, color="lightpink",
                 alpha=0.5, label='year N-1')
plt.fill_between(np.arange(12), year_n, color="skyblue",
                 alpha=0.5, label='year N')

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Out:

[image]

**EDIT:**

```
df = df.set_index('date')
colors = ['gray', 'lightpink', 'skyblue']
plt.fill_between(df['value'], color=colors[type], alpha=0.5)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Out:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not type
```

Comment: Not totally clear what you are trying to do, do you want bar charts for each day with different colors, or areas like in your example? How does the data tie into your example? In terms of trying a solution, can you not just have a `list` or `dictionary` of colors that you reference? Something like `colors = ['gray', 'lightpink', 'skyblue']` and then in your plotting command, `color=colors[type]`.

Comment: Slightly different from the example plot since my data is time series, so I hope to plot it on three areas charts with different colors, the x-axis is `date`. Please see the edit code.

Comment: I add an expected plot in the question, please check.

Comment: Hi, the fill_between function does not work like that, please read https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between.html. Your error is due to the fact that color is a list and type is a string and can not slice or index a list with a string. You should put it insde a for loop and call something like colors[i] where i: 0,1,2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
# let's use datetime type 
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

# the colors
colors = ['gray', 'lightpink', 'skyblue']

# loop and plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i, (t, d) in enumerate(df.groupby('type')):
    d.plot.area(x='date', y='value', label=t, ax=ax, alpha=0.5, color=colors[i])
    
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, off the topic, do you mind answer my question in the last post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69937972/groupby-year-month-and-drop-columns-with-all-nans-in-python