# What input does a custom function take for pandas.resample?

Tags: python, pandas

Forgive me as I'm new to pandas, but I'm trying to resample an array of wind direction measurements by a custom function to do the vector mean:

```
def windavg(direction):
    rads = (direction*np.pi)/180
    s = np.arctan2(np.sum(np.sin(rads)),np.sum(np.cos(rads)))
    mean_direction = ((s*180)/np.pi + 360) % 360
    return mean_direction
```

My dataframe `winddir` looks like this:

[image]

and I've been trying to resample it using:

```
resample_met = winddir.resample('1H',on='date').apply(windavg)
```

but I keep getting the error `TypeError: cannot perform __mul__ with this index type: DatetimeArray`, which is tripping on the first line of the function. I'm confused as to why the resample is trying to perform the function on the dates, as from what I understand from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41300653/pandas-resample-apply-custom-function) I can just use my custom function as a substitute for the standard methods of resampling like `.mean()` or `.sum()`.

What am I misinterpreting about how this function works, and how can I apply this custom function to the resampling process?

Comment: Try to exclude your `date` from your data: `winddir.set_index('date').resample('1H').apply(windavg)`.

Comment: @QuangHoang that was it, thank you!